# Getting the response from Web Api using Angular Controller

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am just trying to figure out what would be the easiest and quickest way to get particular value from WebApi controller.

my web API controller

```
public  IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
 return new string[] { fullname,lastname, email};
}
```

when I try to consume this web API in the angular controller by using the below method

```
 this._httpService.get('/api/user').subscribe(values => {
            this.details= values.json() as string[];
        });
```

it returns all the values (fullname,lastname, email). but what I am trying to get here is lastname.

something like this.details.lastname

Comment: Make sure, your reference object is instantiated properly. Then try.

Comment: Why are you returning `string[]` instead of a proper viewmodel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarity, if you are using Angular (not AngularJS), then the code is called a `component` not a `controller`.

Which version of Angular are you using? If it is > 4.3, then you don't need the `.json()` anymore. The mapping is handled for you automatically.

To answer your question ... the "quickest" way would be something like this (assuming Angular v6):

```
this.http.get<>('/api/user').subscribe(
  details => this.lastName =  details.lastName
);
```

Assuming that `details` is one item, not an array.

But this is definitely not the "best" way.

The best way would be to define an interface for your details and then build a proper client-side service to encapsulate your data access.